# Difference in accessing arrays in PHP 5.3 and 5.4 or some configuration mismatch?

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework2

I'm trying to access nested array element like this:

```
$dbSettings = $sm->get( 'Config' )[ 'doctrine' ][ 'connection' ][ 'orm_default' ][ 'params' ];
```

It's inside `Module.php` of Zend's framework 2 project. `$sm->get('Config')` return an array which I can access with code above locally, with PHP 5.4, while doing so on client's machine, it gives me an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/.../azk/module/Main/Module.php on line 121
```

Is there any difference in PHP 5.3 <=> 5.4 in accessing nested arrays or I have some default PHP configuration which is set differently on clients machne?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html), which is what you are using, was introduced in PHP 5.4 and won't work in PHP 5.3.

So

```
$dbSettings = $sm->get( 'Config' )[ 'doctrine' ][ 'connection' ][ 'orm_default' ][ 'params' ];
```

Would need to be:

```
$dbSettings = $sm->get( 'Config' );
$params     = $dbSettings[ 'doctrine' ][ 'connection' ][ 'orm_default' ][ 'params' ];
```