# Why error with with if (($x = $y)['abc'] == 'test')?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, setting

I have the following code:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) && ($value = mysqli_fetch_array($result))['id'] != $id)
```

And I get the following mistake:

> $Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in [...]

But I don't get the point!

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) && mysqli_fetch_array($result)['id'] != $id)
```

this works fine, but I want to save the result of `mysqli_fetch_array`. And I thought that would easily possible without a second If-Clause.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: With `mysqli` it'll be PHP. I've added the tag.

Comment: move $value = mysqli_fetch_array($result) outside if else

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in accessing arrays in PHP 5.3 and 5.4 or some configuration mismatch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751348/difference-in-accessing-arrays-in-php-5-3-and-5-4-or-some-configuration-mismatch)

Comment: One of the weird ones where the error giving is not actually the problem. It happens especially when it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis are in a weird spot:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) && ($value = mysqli_fetch_array($result))['id'] != $id)
```

Should be:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) && ($value = mysqli_fetch_array($result)['id']) != $id)
```

Or...I'm not sure if this will avoid the syntax error but if you're trying to keep all of the results, try this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) && (($value = mysqli_fetch_array($result))['id']) != $id)
```

I added even more parenthesis hoping the enforced order of operation would make things clearer to the interpreter.